# Send Email to Topic whenever a step in AWS State Machine fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, aws-step-functions

I have a state machine with multiple steps.
I want to send notification whenever a step run successfully or give error.
One solution is to add a SNS step after each step so whenever a step is successful then next step will run which is to send notification but what if a step fails then How can I send email ?
Is there any solution to this problem ?
I know we can set cloud watch rules but it send notification when a complete state machine fails but here I want to get notifications at lower level i.e. at every step of state machine.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your question.

In the AWS Step Functions Console, there's a sample project called **Callback pattern example** which should illustrate what you're trying to achieve:

[image: Step Functions callback pattern]

Step Functions offers error catching functionality which allows you to transition to a specific state based on the error thrown. For more information see this helpful documentation on error handling: [Error Handling in Step Functions - AWS Step Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-error-handling.html)